# Is there a way to shorten this code? maybe a ternary expression?

Tags: java, ternary

```
    if (i <= 33) {
            variable = x;
        } else if (i > 33 && i <= 66) {
            variable = y;
        } else {
            variable = z;
        }
```

Is there a way to shorten this down? I can't find out how to use the ternary operator in this situation.

Comment: What data type is `i` and can you give any restrictions on the range? I'm thinking you could do something like `variable = {x, y, z}[i/33]`

Comment: i is an int ranging from 0 to 100

Comment: I would remove the `i > 33 &&` but otherwise leave it alone. If it's still "too complicated", simply hide it in a method - then it's a one-line call: `variable = toNearestSegment(i);`.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to use some crazy nested ternaries:

```
int variable = i <= 33 ? x : i > 33 && i <= 66 ? y : z
```

... But don't do this.  Make your code readable and maintainable instead!

Also, as @EJP mentions [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23644807/1435657) (which you should thus upvote), the `i > 33` condition is redundant, so you could shorten this to:

```
int variable = i <= 33 ? x : i <= 66 ? y : z
```

I was just grabbing the clauses from your if/else-s directly.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I've seen code like this in my production environment.  It's not fun to debug. :)

Comment: If you have to put a break point you cannot do that on a ternary keep that in mind.

Comment: @vkg Yep.  Hence, "don't do this."  Maybe I should rephrase that to "Please, *please* don't do this!"  Haha

Comment: 8 up votes on an answer even the author agrees you should never do? Seriously?

Comment: @durron597 It was the first and only to actually answer the question. :)  (The original post didn't phrase it as "maybe" a ternary expression.  He explicitly asked how to make a ternary work.)

Comment: Well hopefully you'll give my answer a little love ;)

Comment: The code in the second grey box is easier to read than using multiple `if` or `if/else` statements.  Please do it this way - it's what ternary operators are for.  +1.

Comment: @DavidWallace It's easier to read for veterans.  Not so much the offshore contractors who will be maintaining your code and have the equivalent of Java 101 knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (i <= 33) {
        variable = x;
```

At this point `i` is `<= 33.`

```
    } else if (i > 33 && i <= 66) {
```

At this point we are in the 'else', where `i > 33` by construction, so you don't need to test it again.

```
        variable = y;
    } else {
        variable = z;
    }
```

So you can reduce this to:

```
if (i <= 33) {
        variable = x;
    } else if (i <= 66) {
        variable = y;
    } else {
        variable = z;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    if (i <= 33) variable = x;
    else if (i <= 66) variable = y;
    else variable = z;
```

Since each clause has only one statement, you omit the curly braces and bring the statements to the same line of the clause.

Answer (score 1):

To grant understandability you can first extract it into a method, then:
 * use first answer
 * if you want it even more understandable you can do this

```
private Object valuePerState(int i){
    if (i<33) return x;
    if (i>66) return y;
    return z;
}
```

BTW one step to shorten your issue is to cut done test for 33 which you done twist

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify without ternary operator by reversing the comparison direction:

```
if (i > 66) 
{
    variable = z;
}
else if (i > 33) 
{
    variable = y;
} 
else 
{
    variable = x;
}
```

But as others have noted, you can simplify the comparison condition without reversing direction.

Comment: You can, but don't have to reverse the direction, as [EJP shows](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23644807/119527).

Comment: I didn't say you had to reverse. It's just one way :)

Comment: But it's the only way you mentioned.

Comment: The implication is that it's the only way, contrary to your comment.

Comment: There is no such implication. Point of diminishing return reached.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ternery operator like:

```
if (i <= 33) {
        variable = x;
    } else {
        variable = (i <= 66) ? y : z;
    }
```

But I would argue this is worse than what you have.

Note that is `i > 33` could be removed because it was already implied by the `else`

Answer (score 0):

If you store `x`, `y`, and `z` in an array, you could use division to access the different elements of the array, which would be faster especially if you know that your condition is bounded by, in this case, 0 and 100.

```
index = Math.min(Math.max((i-1) / 33, 0), 2);
variable = x[index];
```

If `i` cannot be less than 0 or bigger than 100, this becomes:

```
index = (i-1) / 33;
variable = x[index];
```

Answer (score 0):

I seem to be late to the party, but anyway.  Here's the way I use chained ternary operators.  It's fairly readable in my opinion.

```
variable = i <= 33 ? x
         : i <= 66 ? y
         : z ;
```

Because of the placement of operators and whitespace, this method also works well with version control:  any new condition you stick in the middle is simply a new line in the diff, leaving the other conditions unchanged.  Also, if so many operators make you nervous, you can of course add parentheses around the conditions.

Answer (score -1):

Since you're using an else clause, you don't have to check against 33 twice:

```
if (i <= 33) {
    variable = x;
} else if (i <= 66) {
    variable = y;
} else {
    variable = z;
}
```

Comment: Redundant. [EJP's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23644807/119527) already demonstrates this.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart EJP's answer wasn't visible when I posted.

Comment: Well it *was*, but your page was not refreshed. The timestamps don't lie.